# A single word for a person who suffers great loss

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Can anybody give me a single word for a person who suffers great loss as in the context below. The word loser is not appropriate:

> Mike lost everything after his failed
>   business venture.
>
> Phillip suffered great loss due to
>   the flood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about "destitute"

> Phillip was left destitute as a result of the flood./ Phillip is now a destitute.

There is also "ruined"

> Philip suffered great loss due to the flood. He is now ruined.

or

"Devastated"

Comment: +1 for destitute, which I have heard used in the way the OP is seeking, as a noun. (See first example [here](http://www.wordnik.com/words/destitute/examples).)

Answer (score 5):

"Victim" is often used for everything from natural disasters to diseases to financial ruin.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

- **[choker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/choker)**:  an unfortunate person who is unable to perform effectively because of nervous tension or agitation.
- **Victim**: One who is harmed by or made to suffer from an act, circumstance, agency, or condition.

Comment: Victim is the answer of the question because my class mahesh tutorials told me

Answer (score 2):

Mike could be called an *unfortunate*:

> [unfortunate](http://www.wordnik.com/words/unfortunate)–**noun**
>   A victim of bad luck.

Phillip could be called a *sufferer*:

> [sufferer](http://www.wordnik.com/words/sufferer)–**noun**
>   One who suffers; a person who endures or undergoes pain, either of body or of mind; one sustaining evil of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

"The bereaved" refers to someone who has suffered great loss, whether through the death of another or otherwise.

Comment: Even when nobody died?  I'm used to "bereaved" applying to people who've lost loved ones, but not to those who've lost money or property.

Comment: "having a close relation or friend who has recently died".

Comment: @Monica Cellio: It refers to great loss. It's just that almost any usage not referring to death is hyperbolic.

Comment: According to etymonline, *[bereaved](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=bereaved)* mostly  applies to loss of loved ones, and *bereft* to loss due to circumstance.

Comment: @jwpat7 Mostly. Not the same as solely.

Answer (score 0):

It holds a negative connotation like loser but if you wanted an adjective sorry could fit.